# An unbounded subset of the reals containing no intervals with the following property.

Tags: measure-theory

I'm trying to find an unbounded subset of the reals, $A$, with the property that:
$m(A\cap I)<0.9m(I) $ for all intervals, $I$. And $m(A)\neq0$. Where $m(X)$ denotes the outer measure of $X\subset\mathbb{R}$.

Thus far, I have concluded that if such a set does exist, clearly it must be uncountable, it must contain no intervals otherwise you cannot satisfy "$m(A\cap I)<0.5m(I) $", but I can't think of much else.

Comment: Is it $0.9$ or $0.5$ as the constant multiplier? (Probably makes no difference, could replace by $c<1$.)

Comment: It must be non-measurable, since in a measurable set almost all points are Lebesgue points, and that means $\lim\limits_{\varepsilon\to 0} \dfrac{m(A \cap (x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon))}{2\varepsilon} = 1$.

Comment: Thank you for your response, Daniel, but I have no requirement that A be measurable - can you think of any examples that satisfy the above criteria?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $0\lt\alpha\lt1$, and suppose $A$ is a subset of $\mathbb R$ such that $m(A\cap I)\lt\alpha\ m(I)$ for every interval I, where $m$ is Lebesgue outer measure on $\mathbb R$.

Consider a fixed interval $I$. Choose an open set $B$ such that $A\cap I\subseteq B$ and $m(B)\lt\alpha\ m(I)$. Write $B=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}I_n$ where the $I_n$'s are pairwise disjoint open intervals, so that $m(B)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}m(I_n)$. Then $m(A\cap I)\le\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}m(A\cap I_n)\lt\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\alpha\ m(I_n)=\alpha\ m(B)\lt\alpha^2\ m(I)$.

Repeating this argument, we have $m(A\cap I)\lt\alpha^km(I)$ for every interval $I$ and every natural $k$, whence $m(A)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a correction of my earlier answer:

Such sets do not exist. This follows from the following improvement on Lebesgue density theorem: Almost every point (in the outer measure sense) of a set of positive outer measure is a density point.

This variation on Lebesgue density theorem was proven in

H. Blumberg, "A theorem on linear point sets", 
Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. Volume 25, Number 8 (1919), p. 350-353.

Comment: This answer seems to assume the set $A$ is required to be measurable. But the question of OP does not assume that. Outer measure exists even for non-measurable sets.

Comment: @coffeemath: Please, see the correction.

Comment: Thanks for that more general theorem. It also settles another question once going around grad school, as to whether there is a set perfectly mixed in that it meets each interval with half the measure. (And +1)